# DB2 casting to DECIMAL

Tags: casting, db2, decimal

I'm trying to cast a number to DECIMAL(10,2).
If I understand well, a number like "1234567890" should be a valid
DECIMAL(10,2).
But when I try to cast it, it returns an -413 error:

"OVERFLOW OR UNDERFLOW OCCURRED DURING NUMERIC DATA TYPE CONVERSION"

This is the SQL:

```
select CAST( 1234567890 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

As I see it, the problem is that it is adding two zero decimal positions,
so the total length is 12, which is not valid number for a (10,2).

In fact, if I try to CAST it to (12,2) it works (showing "1234567890.00" ).

I wonder if this is an error or if I'm doing something wrong.
CASTING to (12,2) does not seem to be a valid option, because it will
accept numbers like "1234567890.12" that should not be valid for a (10,2).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`DECIMAL` data type](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html) is specified by providing two numbers:

1. The first integer is the precision of the number; that is, the total number of digits; it may range from 1 to 31.
2. The second integer is the scale of the number; that is, the number of digits to the right of the decimal point; it may range from 0 to the precision of the number.

In your case `DECIMAL(10,2)` means a total of 10 digits with 2 of them used for the scale. The number `1234567890` therefore does not fit, `12345678.90` would.

Comment: Thank you, I mixed it up with the concept of totalDigits and fractionDigits from XML. I thought it worked the same way, but it seems it doesn't